# Calculating the off impedance of a relay output by a multimeter

Tags: relay, impedance

I'm trying to calculate the output OFF impedance i.e. the impedance caused by its RC snubber of [this SSR](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/140b/0900766b8140b509.pdf).

So I perform the following test:

[image]

Zc is the relay's OFF impedance and Zv is the fluke 114 multi-meter's measurement in loZ setting. [In this document](https://dam-assets.fluke.com/s3fs-public/2793260_6116_ENG_A_W.PDF) loZ impedance of the multi-meter is given as: ~3 kΩ < 500 pF. A you see above, for 229V AC mains voltage the rms voltage across Zv is 6.5V.

So I took Zc as 3k to calculate Zv. This yielded Zv as around 102k.
But the datasheet of the relay says "Max. Off state leakage current (rms): 10mA" this requires n OFF impedance of 230/10mA = 23k.

But my measurement yields 102k.

Where am I doing wrong? And what is 500 pF in the multimmeter input impedance? Does that mean multimeter's inout imepdance is |3k + j*(1/2*pi*50*500pF)| or as in my example only 3k at 50Hz?

Comment: The rated value is a maximum, and a higher resistance would mean lower leakage current, so this is reasonable.

Comment: I see, how about me taking 3k as multi-meter impedance? Is that correct? Or should I include 500pF?

Comment: The 500pF is in parallel, not series, so it shouldn't affect this reading very much. At least, I think.

Comment: That made Xc for the multimeter 6.4Meg. 6.4Meg in parallel with 3k is 2.99k.So it has tiny effect.